# PHP MySQL adding to existing value in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am a little bit stuck with a PHP script.

The script is for a radio station and it needs to do the following:

1. Count how many times a radio presenter has booked a slot for the current day. The slots are stored in a table in a database and I would use the code `date("l")` to determine the current day and then search for all rows which have "day" set to whatever the value of `date("l")` is.
2. Then I would need to find out how many hours the presenter already has stored in the "monthly_slots" column in the "users" table in the row which has their username. `"SELECT monthly_slots FROM users"`
3. Then I'd need to add whatever the value of the amount of slots the presenter has completed today with the amount of slots which already exist in the monthly_slots column.

Below is my code for this

```
$currentday = date("l");
$currentslots = mysql_query("SELECT monthly_slots FROM users");
mysql_query("
    UPDATE users
    SET slots = (SELECT COUNT(*) + "$currentslots" 
                 FROM timetable 
                 WHERE timetable.username = users.username 
                   AND day = "$currentday"
                )
");
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you add the `"$currentslots"` outside the query i.e. first count the exiting one's and then add 1 to it. Also, the correct format would be `".$currentslots."`

Comment: or, since you're using double quotes, the format would be: `"normal text $variable more normal text"`

Comment: also, `$currentslots` is a resource variable, you would have to get the number of rows first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the value returned by the resource

```
$currentday = date("l");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT monthly_slots FROM users");
$currentslots = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


mysql_query("
    UPDATE users
    SET slots = (SELECT COUNT(*) + "$currentslots" 
                 FROM timetable 
                 WHERE timetable.username = users.username 
                   AND day = "$currentday"
                )
");
```

Comment: At the moment when I run the code it replaces the values in `monthly_slots` with how many slots the presenter has booked for that day. It doesn't add the existing amount to that

Answer (score 0):

$currentslots is a mysql resource not a number, use mysql_num_rows($currentslots) instead

Comment: $currentslotsResult = mysql_query("SELECT monthly_slots FROM users");
$currentslots = mysql_num_rows($currentslotsResult);

Comment: That causes the monthly_slots to be updated with the amount of rows that are in the users table

Answer (score 0):

// Current date

```
$currentday = date("l");
```

// Find the number of hours in the users table

```
$exec_monthlyslots = mysql_query("SELECT monthly_slots FROM users");
$currentslots=mysql_fetch_assoc($exec_monthlyslots);
```

// instead of counting all columns, use the column id you want to count `COUNT(*)`

```
$new_query="UPDATE users
            SET slots = (
                            (
                                SELECT COUNT(*)
                                FROM timetable 
                                WHERE timetable.username = users.username 
                                AND day = ".$currentday."
                            )
                            + ".$currentslots['monthly_slots']."
                        )
            ";

mysql_query($new_query);
```

This should help you out. Tell me if it doesn't.